# Angular 1.5 component onChanges is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Since we have pretty big Angular 1.x application, we can't upgrade it fully to Angular 2 but I love the new architecture. Version 1.5 brings amazing `component`s to the old same app. As all cool stuff, it lacks documentation ;-)

So, here is a question. I have those two lines in the controller's definition:

```
this.$onInit = setType;
this.$onChanges = setType;
```

the first is working, whilst the second isn't. I am using `'<'` binding. So on the first load, the component's state is set according to passed values, whilst the changes are not being reflected. I got the hope that it should work from [1] and [2].

[1] https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

[2] https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html

**UPD** Ok, I have learnt that it is not supposed to work: 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14030

Does anybody know good workarounds?

**UPD2** It works as of 1.5.3

Comment: Quick feedback : I had to do an `angular.copy()` with an Object (not primitive) when I modify values to trigger `$onChange()` in the child component.

Comment: Try this $doCheck http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2016/07/component-lifecycle-docheck-angular-15x_22.html

Answer (score 26):

As of AngularJs 1.5.3, supposing ctrl.someModel is bound one-way in a child component, the following won't trigger $onChanges.

```
function get() { 
  api.getData().then( (data) => {
    ctrl.someModel.data = data
  }
}
```

It seems like updating properties of an object won't be recognized as an update.

This is how I currently get around it. I don't believe it to be the best solution, but it triggers $onChanges. I create a deep copy of my initial model, add the data as one of it's properties, and then set my initial model to the value of the new object. Essentially, I update the whole object, which is picked up by the lifecycle hook:

```
function get() { 
  api.getData().then( (data='42') => {
    const updatedModel = angular.copy(ctrl.someModel)
    updatedModel.data = data
    ctrl.someModel = updatedModel
  }
}
```

And in the child component (assuming the model as been binded as 'data'):

```
this.$onInit = function(bindings) {
  if (bindings.data && bindings.data.currentValue) {
    console.log(bindings.data.currentValue) // '42' 
  }
}
```

Comment: That's actually good solution since you are essentially using immutable data, so it would work perfect with flux and all this stuff.

Comment: It's a good way of fixing this. But it can be done better. I've written a blogpost with an example on how to use ImmutableJS to fix this in a 'cleaner' way. http://blog.kwintenp.com/the-onchanges-lifecycle-hook/

Comment: I had a similar problem, but since I was dealing with an array instead of copy I just used `Array.slice()` which returns a copy of the array and the `$onChanges` actually fired in the component. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Dealing with `$onChanges` is tricky. Actually, thats why in version 1.5.8 they introduced the `$doCheck`, similar to Angular 2 ngDoCheck.

This way, you can manually listen to changes **inside** the object being listened, which **does not** occur with the `$onChanges` hook (called only when the reference of the object is changed). Its the same thing, but it gets called for *every digest cycle* allowing you to check for changes manually (but better then watches).

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, both the `$onChanges` and `$onInit` method should work with AngularJS version 1.5.3.

I've created a [plnkr that demonstrates both usages](http://plnkr.co/edit/sqJfKQ9keHfAGpp2ZoHY?p=preview).

It has two components, an outer and an inner component, where a value is bound from the outer to the inner component using the one-way binding operator `<`. An input field updates the outer component's value. On every keyboard input into the input field, the `$onChanges` method is fired (open your console to see).

```
angular.module("app", [])
.component("outer", {
    restrict: "E", 
    template: `<input ng-model=$ctrl.value> <br /> 
            <inner value="$ctrl.value">
            </inner>`
})  
.component("inner", {
    restrict: "E", 
    template: `{{$ctrl.value}}`, 
    bindings: {
       value: "<"
    },
    controller: function(){
       function setType() { 
          console.log("called");
       }
       this.$onInit = setType;
       this.$onChanges = setType;
   }
});
```

Comment: 1.5.3 has not been released yet though, has it? I was referring 1.5.0, which was the only one in 1.5.x branch by time of writing the initial question.

Comment: 1.5.3 has been released about a week ago. The hooks were introduced in that version :).

Comment: Is it possible that the $onChanges event isn't fired if you use one-way bindings to pass an object, and the parent component changes only simple property on the object ? 
See this pen: http://codepen.io/vandenbusschebr/pen/MyrjOa

Comment: @KwintenP oh, my bad, resolution was hardcoded so bower did not update :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: @BramVandenbussche seems so. If I change `something='vm1.thing'` to `something='vm1.thing.someProp'` in your code, it works as a charm. Not sure if it's a bug or a feature though :-)

Comment: I've written a blogpost on the subject an proposed a way to fix this using ImmutableJS. You can check it out here: http://blog.kwintenp.com/the-onchanges-lifecycle-hook/ @BramVandenbussche

Comment: @leitasat It is a feature. Look at the blog. If you would perform a deep comparison, the performance would become very poor :).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, $onChanges angular lifecycle hook trigger when angular find the change in reference ( not the property in the changed object ), so in order to invoke the $onChanges in the child, in the parent, assign the new object. for example,

```
angular.module("app", [])
.component("outer", {
    restrict: "E", 
    controller : function(){
        this.value = {};
        this.userButtonClick = function(someValue){
            this.value = angular.copy(someValue);
        }
    },
    template: `<input ng-click="$ctrl.userButtonClick({somevalue : "value"})" /> 
   <br /> 
            <inner value="$ctrl.value">
            </inner>`
    })           
.component("inner", {
        restrict: "E", 
        template: `{{$ctrl.value}}`, 
        bindings: {
           value: "<"
        },
        controller: function(){
           function setType() { 
              console.log("called");
           }
           this.$onInit = setType;
           this.$onChanges = function(changeObj){
               console.log("changed value",changeObj.value.currentValue);
           }
       }
    });
```

Don't use $doCheck unless you really want to trigger a callback in every digest cycle, because it is invoked in every $digest cycle no matter some binding change or not.